# Combinatory logic equivalent to System F

Tags: type-theory, combinatory-logic

Simply typed lambda calculus has a combinatory logic equivalent with the same expressive power without the need of defining names via lambda abstraction.

Is there a formalism as powerful as System F but based on combinatory logic?

Comment: Going in a different direction on the lambda cube: [polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11406786/573420). [Similar question on TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/22147/3131).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I know these questions, but I don't need the extra power of the type system they ask for. I only need sufficient power to type lambda encoded natural numbers.

Comment: I thought that combinatory logic is untyped, and is equivalent to the untyped lambda calculus, not to the simply-typed one. I mean, we have things like `kkk=k` which can not be typed in STLC. Can you elaborate?